# Posicionamento de colunas no bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, panel

Tenho 3 colunas, elas estão posicionadas assim:

```
Dados Basicos | Endereço    
Contato
```

Então quando é feito a responsavidade ele fica assim

```
Dados Basicos
Endereço
Contato
```

Porem preciso que seja feito assim:

```
Dados Basicos | Contato
Endereço
```

Então quando for feito a responsividade ele continue assim:

```
Dados Basicos
Endereço
Contato
```

```html
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Dados Basicos
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Endereço
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Contatos
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Poste todo o seu HTML ai para fazermos um teste, mas acredito que bastava você trocar a ordem, colocar "contatos" no lugar de endereço e vicexvesa e ja daria certo...Eu acho, por isso preciso do html completo e do css

Comment: se eu fizer isso, ao fazer a responsividade  o panel Contatos ficaria antes de Endereço, porem quero que a ordem seja Dados Basicos > Endereço > Contatos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tente assim:**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Dados Basicos
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
             <div class="panel panel-default">
                 <div class="panel-body">
                     Endereço
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            Contatos
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[EXEMPLO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lgx2tx5/)

Comment: Valeu caro Jefferson, isso mesmo que queriamos..
Abrass

Comment: De nada @HenriqueAbreu! Estamos ai pra ajudar!